# How to serialize named tuple with np array to file

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, pickle

How to serialize named tuple with np array to file?

I know how to serialize/deserialize an np_array.

```
import numpy as np

a = [
    np.arange(300),
    np.arange(200)
]

np.save('output.pkl', a, allow_pickle=True)
```

But for my case, I am dealing with a named tuple with a string and a NumPy array.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Address', 'city embedding')
```

So here city is string and embedding is NumPy array.

Not sure how to persist a list of Points to file and load it back.

Any help/pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Exploring, can you atleast confirm if answer worked for you or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`cloudpickle`](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle). Cloudpickle makes it possible to serialize Python constructs not supported by the default pickle module from the Python standard library.

```
import cloudpickle

Point = namedtuple('Address', 'city embedding') 
pick = Point(CITY_EMBEDDING_CONTAINER)
with open('deleteme.cloudpickle', 'wb') as f:
    cloudpickle.dump(pick, f)
```